# How to go from the last frame to the first within the first scene when you have multiple scenes in flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, flash-8

I have 3 scenes in my flash, so when I run the movie it goes through all scenes, however I have a button which send you to the next scene.

When he is not pressed I want that just first scene( in my case Scene 1 ) is looping. I mean I have 30 frames in Scene 1 and when it is on frame 30 I want to go to frame 1 of Scene 1.

How to do that using **ActionScript2.0**?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Put a keyframe on the last frame of your first scene containing the code:

```
gotoAndPlay(1,"Scene 1"); //assuming "Scene 1" is the name of your first scene.
```